# How to resize gtk.gdk.Pixmap

Tags: python, pygtk, gtk, gdk, gdkpixbuf

I am created an instance of `gtk.gdk.Pixmap`, and painted on it something. For example:

```
pixmap = gtk.gdk.Pixmap(widget.window,100,800)
pixmap.draw_rectangle(gc, True, 0, 0, 100, 800)
pixmap.draw_line(gc, 0, 0,100, 800)
```

How can I to resize the `Pixmap`?  One way that I see is to copy the `Pixmap` into a `PixBuf` using `gtk.gdk.Pixbuf.get_from_drawable`, then resize the `Pixbuf`, and then copy the `Pixbuf` to the `Pixmap`

Is there any way to do this without all the copying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it's not possible without all this copying. Please note that GdkPixmap and GdkPixbuf are deprecated in favor of Cairo.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, those are deprecated.

More importantly, GdkPixmap is a server-side resource - the contents of the pixmap live in the X server's memory.  When you do get_from_drawable(), you are asking for those contents to be transferred to your application, which is expensive.

Instead, create a Cairo image suface, and do your drawing there.  This is a client-side resource, so you won't get that performance penalty.  Image surfaces can be scaled by drawing them to another surface with a suitable transformation.

Comment: Cool, I didn't actually know that copying involved a server-client roundtrip.